# Postgres 9.6.1 Full Text Search dictionaries for most spoken languages

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, full-text-search

I am trying to run full text search operations, such as `to_tsvector`, `to_tsquery`, etc and have a need for [dictionaries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SIMPLE-DICTIONARY) in about 80+ languages.

Postgres seems to only come with 16 language configurations, with an additional two I am testing for Chinese (`jiebacfg` and `testzhcg` aka `ZHParse`). I'm looking for documentation or a repository of other languages beyond these.

```
mydatabase=# \dF

               List of text search configurations
   Schema   |    Name    |              Description              
------------+------------+---------------------------------------
 pg_catalog | danish     | configuration for danish language
 pg_catalog | dutch      | configuration for dutch language
 pg_catalog | english    | configuration for english language
 pg_catalog | finnish    | configuration for finnish language
 pg_catalog | french     | configuration for french language
 pg_catalog | german     | configuration for german language
 pg_catalog | hungarian  | configuration for hungarian language
 pg_catalog | italian    | configuration for italian language
 pg_catalog | norwegian  | configuration for norwegian language
 pg_catalog | portuguese | configuration for portuguese language
 pg_catalog | romanian   | configuration for romanian language
 pg_catalog | russian    | configuration for russian language
 pg_catalog | simple     | simple configuration
 pg_catalog | spanish    | configuration for spanish language
 pg_catalog | swedish    | configuration for swedish language
 pg_catalog | turkish    | configuration for turkish language
 public     | jiebacfg   | configuration for jieba
 public     | testzhcfg  | 
(18 rows)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name typo - 9.6.1

Comment: You may want to look at some of OpenOfiice's [Ispell (MySpell/Hunspell) dictionaries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-ISPELL-DICTIONARY) (PostgreSQL docs have *some* directions about how to import them, but I have never done it before).

Comment: @pozs yikes, installing even one additional language dictionary (https://lasr.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell-dictionaries.html) is arduous

Answer (score 3):

As **pozs** commented you can get dictionary files from [OpenOffice](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/search?f%5B0%5D=field_project_tags%3A157) (or [LibreOffice](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions?getCategories=Dictionary&getCompatibility=any)) extensions. From [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-ISPELL-DICTIONARY):

> To create an Ispell dictionary perform these steps:
>
> - download dictionary configuration files. OpenOffice extension files    have the .oxt extension. It is necessary to extract .aff and .dic files, change extensions to .affix and .dict. For some dictionary files it is also needed to convert characters to the UTF-8 encoding with commands (for example, for a Norwegian language dictionary):
>
> iconv -f ISO_8859-1 -t UTF-8 -o nn_no.affix nn_NO.aff
>   iconv -f ISO_8859-1 -t UTF-8 -o nn_no.dict nn_NO.dic
>
> - copy files to the $SHAREDIR/tsearch_data directory
> - load files into PostgreSQL with the following command:
>
> CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY english_hunspell (
>       TEMPLATE = ispell,
>       DictFile = en_us,
>       AffFile = en_us,
>       Stopwords = english);

Also there is a list of extensions which provide easy way of dictionary installing. You can download them from [github](https://github.com/postgrespro/hunspell_dicts/).